# How to divide a time type variable by 2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable of type `TIME`, I need to divide the time of this variable by 2.

My SQL code:

```
DECLARE @TEMPO AS TIME = '01:31:00'

SELECT (@TEMPO / 2 ) AS RESULT

--the result should be: 00:45:30
```

SQL Server however throws an error:

> Operand type clash: time is incompatible with int

Every help is welcome!

Comment: If the time is: 01:31:00
 The result will be: 00:45:30

Comment: I think maybe your TIME is time elapsed?  then its not a time datatype, you woudl use int, or something different

Comment: The answer of @John Cappelletti solve my problem, convert TIME to FLOAT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just another option is to convert the time to `datetime` and then to `float`, and then divide by two.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @TEMPO AS TIME = '01:31:00'

Select convert(time,convert(datetime,convert(float,convert(datetime,@Tempo))/2))
```

**Returns**

```
00:45:30.0000000
```

Comment: @sergioBertolazzo Happy to help

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks... I never understood why we can't convert time to a float.  After all, it would just be a decimal representation of 24 hours.

Answer (score 7):

Using `TIMEFROMPARTS`(SQL Server 2012+):

```
DECLARE @TEMPO AS TIME = '01:31:00';
DECLARE @i INT = DATEDIFF(s, '00:00:00',@TEMPO)/2;

SELECT  TIMEFROMPARTS(@i/3600%60, @i/60%60 ,@i%60,0,0);
-- 00:45:30
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52651187e93c355883f81e74d9b59d5b)**

Comment: Thank you for answer, in the fiddle work perfect, but in my SQL Server 2008 R2 returns a error: 'DATEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @sergioBertolazzo TIMEFROMPARTS is available starting from SQL Server 2012. Please consider upgrading before July: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 3):

The time data type represents a **Time Of Day**, not an amount of time or **Duration**.

You can't divide a time of day by an integer, it isn't a concept that makes sense.   What is 2 o'clock divided by 2?

If you are trying to represent a duration or amount of time, then store it as an integer of your lowest level of granularity, and then divide it.  Then if you want you can display it in a formatted string of Hours:Minutes.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to convert type INT to TIME?

Comment: I have a feeling this is an XY question.  First tell me why you think you want to convert INT to TIME.

Comment: because the data table has the TIME column, I can not change the column type because a production system that writes this information. I'm just creating an output report.

Comment: So then don't you actually need to convert TIME to INT?

Comment: The answer of @John Cappelletti solve my problem, convert TIME to FLOAT.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @TEMPO AS TIME = '01:31:00';
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,'0:0',@TEMPO)/2,'0:0')) AS [RESULT];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the time into an integer number of milliseconds using `DateDiff`, perform the arithmetic, and then use `DateAdd` to convert back to a `Time`:

```
declare @Tempo as Time = '01:31:00';
select @Tempo as Tempo;
set @Tempo = DateAdd( ms, DateDiff( ms, 0, @Tempo ) / 2, 0 );
select @Tempo as HalfTempo;
```