# How to sum a Time column (with millisecond) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column of type `TIME`, I need SUM this column with the **millisecond** included.

My SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_USER(
        ID INT,
        TEMPO TIME(7)
    )

INSERT INTO #TEMP_USER 
VALUES
 (1, '00:52:37.5000000')
,(1, '00:52:37.5000000')
,(1, '00:52:37.5000000')
,(1, '00:52:37.5000000')
,(1, '00:52:37.5000000')
,(1, '00:52:37.5000000')
,(1, '00:52:37.5000000')
,(1, '00:52:37.5000000')

SELECT 
    ID
    ,SUM(TEMPO) AS RESULT
FROM #TEMP_USER
GROUP BY ID

--THE RESULT OF SUM SHOULD BE: '07:01:00'
```

SQL Server however throws an error:

> Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.

Every help is welcome!

Comment: You can only sum durations and not timestamps. Which is why I suggest converting to the smallest denominator (half a second), add those up and re-format to display a time.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your previous question, [How to divide a time type variable by 2 in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136295/how-to-divide-a-time-type-variable-by-2-in-sql-server) but instead of divide by 2 you're adding together? Have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: @Sami, This answer returns me '1900-01-01 07:01:00.000', do you know how I can remove the DATE and just leave the TIME?

Comment: what format do you want the result in?  Milliseconds, or HHHHHH:MM:SS.mmm ?

Comment: @sergioBertolazzo `SELECT ID,
       CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', TEMPO)), '00:00:00.000') AS TIME)
FROM #TEMP_USER
GROUP BY ID`

Comment: @Cato i need the format -> "HH:MM:SS.mmmmmmm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give it in milliseconds

```
SELECT 
    ID
    ,SUM(datediff(ms,cast('0:0' as time),TEMPO)) AS RESULT
FROM #TEMP_USER
GROUP BY ID;
```

or for formatted over 24 hours, you could try

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_USER(
        ID INT,
        TEMPO TIME(7)
    )

INSERT INTO #TEMP_USER 
VALUES
 (1, '01:59:37.5100000')
,(1, '23:00:00.0010000');



SELECT 
        ID
        ,datediff(ms,cast('0:0' as time),tempo) AS RESULT
    FROM #TEMP_USER

    SELECT cast(IQ.RESULT / (60* 60 *  1000) as nvarchar(8)) + ':' + REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(cast(dateadd(ms,RESULT % 3600000,cast('0:0' as time)) as nvarchar(40))) as nvarchar(13)))
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        ID
        ,SUM(datediff(ms,cast('0:0' as time),TEMPO)) AS RESULT
    FROM #TEMP_USER
    GROUP BY ID
    ) IQ;



drop table #TEMP_USER ;
```

Comment: This example work perfect. Thank you man.

Answer (score 3):

Take a difference as numeric & do the `sum()` :

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MS, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS, 0, TEMPO)), 0)  AS TIME(0))
FROM #TEMP_USER;
```

Comment: This naive approach works only if the total duration always stays less than 24 hours, which is worth noting. `TIME` does not store durations.

Comment: it works fine with your sample data, but if you had one of your values set to 23:52:37.5000000, or you had 40 of your existing test values - are you happy with the result?  It's your call though.

Comment: @Cato I had not thought of it, and this example does not really work for more than 24 hours